# Is there a way to merge pandas dataframes on row and column index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two pandas data frames that share the same index as well as some columns. pd.merge creates duplicate columns, but I would like to merge on both axes at the same time.

tried pd.merge and pd.concat but did not get the right result.

my try: df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')

df1

```
     Var#1  Var#2  Var#3  Var#4  Var#5  Var#6  Var#7
ID                                                  
323      7      6      8    7.0    2.0    2.0   10.0
324      2      1      5    3.0    4.0    2.0    1.0
675      9      8      1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
676      3      7      2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

df2

```
     Var#6  Var#7  Var#8  Var#9
ID                             
675      1      9      2      8
676      3      2      0      7
```

ideally I would get:

df3

```
     Var#1  Var#2  Var#3  Var#4  Var#5  Var#6  Var#7 Var#8   Var#9
ID                                                  
323      7      6      8    7.0    2.0    2.0   10.0  NaN    NaN
324      2      1      5    3.0    4.0    2.0    1.0  NaN    NaN
675      9      8      1    NaN    NaN    1      9    2      8
676      3      7      2    NaN    NaN    3      2    0      7
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick. I was not aware of that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, use [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df3=df1.combine_first(df2)
print(df3)

      Var#1  Var#2  Var#3  Var#4  Var#5  Var#6  Var#7  Var#8  Var#9
ID                                                                
323      7      6      8    7.0    2.0    2.0   10.0    NaN    NaN
324      2      1      5    3.0    4.0    2.0    1.0    NaN    NaN
675      9      8      1    NaN    NaN    1.0    9.0    2.0    8.0
676      3      7      2    NaN    NaN    3.0    2.0    0.0    7.0
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that. I would really like to have values from the same column in both data frames in one single column  in the output, e.g. there should not be two columns named Var#6.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat and group the data

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], 1).groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).first()

    Var#1   Var#2   Var#3   Var#4   Var#5   Var#6   Var#7   Var#8   Var#9
ID                                  
323 7.0     6.0     8.0     7.0     2.0     2.0     10.0    NaN     NaN
324 2.0     1.0     5.0     3.0     4.0     2.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
675 9.0     8.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     9.0     2.0     8.0
676 3.0     7.0     2.0     NaN     NaN     3.0     2.0     0.0     7.0
```

Comment: @anky_91, thanks. We all are at a different stage of learning here:)